# ReactJS Router problems

Tags: api, url, reactjs, react-router

I want to create a small spa, that has a side nav.

The side nav needs to be created from the **category** using the api:

```
[{
  "category": "dogs",
  "available": [
   {
     "name": "pedro",
     "breed": "chihuahua"
   },
   {
     "name": "roxane"
     "breed": "beagle"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "category": "cat",
  "available": [
  {
    "name": "garfield",
    "breed": "tobby"
  }
 ]
}
```

This api would give a side nav:

- dog
- cat

**What I want to create**

I want the side nav to be able to handle any number of categories that come from the api, example if the api contains dogs, cats, turtles, birds, etc. It must be able to handle the categories.

Also, I want the url to be
/pets/*category type*

example:

if user clicks dogs

/pets/dogs

**My attempt**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

import LayoutContent from './LayoutContent.jsx';

class SideNav extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <nav>
        <a>
           <Link to="/${this.props.data.name}" component={LayoutContent}>{this.props.data.name}</Link>
        </a>
     </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default SideNav;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing pretty well...you can keep all the same code, except change `Link` to

```
<Link to={`/pets/${this.props.data.name}`}>{this.props.data.name}</Link>
```

to get the layout how you want. The component doesn't go in the link though, you declare the route in the main component of react, like [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/active-links/app.js#L61).That's where you specify the components.

So, assuming you've implemented the routes properly, something like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
    <Route path="/pets/:cat" component={Category}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

where the `App` component implements `SideNav`

then, you can reference the [route params](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params) and make an ajax query like this

```
class ShowCats extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/api/${this.props.params.cat`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({pets: json}))
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.pets ? this.state.pets : 'Fetching pets!'
  }
}
```

might have to fiddle with this, but that's the general idea!